# How to remove rempty duplicate dates from line chart in streamlit via plotly?

Tags: date, plotly, axis, streamlit

I have the below line graph:

[image]

by this code:

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
fig_col1, fig_col2,fig_col3 = st.columns(3)

with fig_col1:
    st.markdown("### First Chart")
    fig = px.line(df, y='revenue', x="calendar_date")
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%m-%d"))
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

How do I remove the dupilcate date values? The data is not repeating any dates, but the empty date comes up. When I hover over say the second `07-20`, there is no data presented. I have no idea why this is coming up.

I want the x-axis date to be only 1 of each. For example `07-20` should only write once.

Comment: I don't think there are duplicates,  it's due  to the column.  You can try to plot outside  the `fig_col1` to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't happening because there are duplicate dates – it looks like the datetimes in your data are occurring on 7-20, 7-21, and 7-22, but the default zoom setting for the chart is such that there is an additional tick mark between 7-20 and 7-21 occurring at `7-20-22 12:00:00`, but because `tickformat="%m-%d"` shows only the month and day, the hour is being cut off.

Depending on what you want to see, you can set `tickformat="%m-%d-%h"` so that the hour is visible too.

Or if you only want to see the day no matter how far you zoom in, you can force the tickmarks to be 1 day apart using `fig.update_xaxes(dtick="D1")`. Some further documentation on dtick can be found [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar-dtick).

Comment: this is exactly what i needed: `fig.update_xaxes(dtick="D1")`

Comment: thank you this is helpful. I had months on the xasis and the month was repeating. dtick-'M1' fixed it.